# What is the best way to get intellij keybindings in Monodevelop/Xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin-studio

What is the best way to get intellij keybindings in Monodevelop/Xamarin studio  (in a windows machine)

tried [this](https://github.com/EugenMayer/MonoDevelopIntellijizor) but did not affect the keybindings behaviour :|

Comment: I updated those key binding from the original Github repo and the creator accepted the pull request so you can get the updated list from either repo; his or mine.

Comment: I have just tried this (not on a mac) and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try copying the binding again, then launch XS/MD and go to Preferences/KeyBinding and see if you have any 'Conflicts' listed, if you do, exit XS/MD, edit the file and launch XS/MD again (It seems if you edit them within the IDE it resets the file due to the conflicts and you lose all the bindings...)

Comment: ahh I see what is happening, I was testing this with a few comands that use Control key, and in yours that is _Meta_ , will send a PR :D

Comment: Ok, the original author of key bindings was on OS-X, thus the use of the Meta key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those key binding contain conflicts with XS and MD version 5.0.

I forked that project and modified three conflicts in order to get this to load.

https://github.com/sushihangover/MonoDevelopIntellijizor

I actually used these a year ago but while I love Intellij (for ActionScript coding), its Function Key binding are so non-OS-X based...

Here is the updated "Custom.mac-kb.xml" in case Github is down, hahaha:

```
<schemes version="1.0">
  <scheme name="current">
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.ProjectCommands.Debug" shortcut="F5" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.ProjectCommands.Run" shortcut="Shift+F10" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.SearchCommands.GotoType" shortcut="Meta+N" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.Debugger.BreakpointPad" shortcut="Meta+Shift+F8" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Debugger.DebugCommands.Debug" shortcut="F5" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Debugger.DebugCommands.StepInto" shortcut="F7" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Debugger.DebugCommands.StepOver" shortcut="F8" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Debugger.DebugCommands.StepOut" shortcut="Shift+F8" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.SearchCommands.NextBookmark" shortcut="Meta+F11" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.SearchCommands.PrevBookmark" shortcut="Shift+F11" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.SearchCommands.ToggleBookmark" shortcut="F11" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.WindowCommands.SwitchSplitWindow" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.ErrorListPad" shortcut="Alt+Shift+E" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.Debugger.LocalsPad" shortcut="Meta+D|L" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.Debugger.StackTracePad" shortcut="Meta+D|C" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.Debugger.DebugCommands.ExpressionEvaluator" shortcut="Meta+D|Q" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.Debugger.WatchPad" shortcut="Meta+D|W" />
    <binding command="Pad|ClassPad" shortcut="Alt+Shift+C" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport.PropertyPad" shortcut="Alt+Shift+P" />
    <binding command="Pad|ProjectPad" shortcut="Alt+Shift+S" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.TaskListPad" shortcut="Alt+Shift+T" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport.ToolboxPad" shortcut="Alt+Shift+B" />
    <binding command="Pad|ConnectionManagerPad" shortcut="Alt+Shift+D" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.HelpTree" shortcut="Alt+Shift+F1" />
    <binding command="Pad|MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport.DocumentOutlinePad" shortcut="Meta+F12" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Refactoring.RefactoryCommands.FindDerivedClasses" shortcut="Meta+Alt+B" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Refactoring.RefactoryCommands.FindReferences" shortcut="Alt+F7" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Refactoring.RefactoryCommands.GotoDeclaration" shortcut="Meta+B" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Debugger.DebugCommands.AddTracepoint" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Debugger.DebugCommands.ExpressionEvaluator" shortcut="Alt+F8" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.CodeFormatting.CodeFormattingCommands.FormatSelection" shortcut="Meta+Alt+L" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Refactoring.RefactoryCommands.IntroduceConstant" shortcut="Meta+Alt+C" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.EditCommands.IndentSelection" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.EditCommands.ToggleCodeComment" shortcut="Meta+/" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.EditCommands.UnIndentSelection" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.EditCommands.ToggleAllFoldings" shortcut="Meta+Shift+=" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.EditCommands.ToggleFolding" shortcut="Meta+=" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.CloseFile" shortcut="Meta+Escape" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.CloseAllFiles" shortcut="Meta+Shift+Escape" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileTabCommands.CloseAllButThis" shortcut="Meta+Alt+Shift+Escape" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.NewFile" shortcut="Meta+Alt+Insert" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.OpenFile" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.PrintPreviewDocument" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.PrintDocument" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.Exit" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.SaveAs" shortcut="Meta+Alt+S" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.NewProject" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.SaveAll" shortcut="Meta+S" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.NUnit.Commands.TestCommands.RunAllTests" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.NUnit.Commands.TestCommands.ShowTestDetails" shortcut="Meta+Alt+T" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport.Commands.SwitchBetweenRelatedFiles" shortcut="Meta+Alt+Home" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.ProjectCommands.Build" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.ProjectCommands.BuildSolution" shortcut="Meta+F9" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.ProjectCommands.Rebuild" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.ProjectCommands.RebuildSolution" shortcut="Meta+Alt+Shift+B" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Refactoring.RefactoryCommands.IntegrateTemporaryVariable" shortcut="Meta+Alt+N" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.SearchCommands.GotoLineNumber" shortcut="Meta+G" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.SearchCommands.GotoFile" shortcut="Meta+Shift+N" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.NavigateToDialog.Commands.NavigateTo" shortcut="Meta+Alt+Shift+N" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.DeleteToLineEnd" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.DocumentEnd" shortcut="Meta+Page_Down" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.CSharp.ExpandCommands.ShrinkSelection" shortcut="Meta+Shift+W" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.CSharp.ExpandCommands.ExpandSelection" shortcut="Meta+W" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.GotoMatchingBrace" shortcut="Meta+]" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.XmlEditor.Commands.RunXslTransform" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.ShowCodeTemplateWindow" shortcut="Meta+J" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.MoveBlockDown" shortcut="Meta+Shift+Down" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.MoveBlockUp" shortcut="Meta+Shift+Up" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionMoveEnd" shortcut="Shift+End" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.ShowParameterCompletionWindow" shortcut="Meta+P" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.ToggleBlockSelectionMode" shortcut="Alt+Shift+Insert" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.DeleteLine" shortcut="Shift+Delete" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.ToggleCompletionSuggestionMode" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionMoveToDocumentEnd" shortcut="Meta+Shift+Page_Down" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionMoveToDocumentStart" shortcut="Meta+Shift+Page_Up" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.DocumentStart" shortcut="Meta+Page_Up" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionMoveHome" shortcut="Shift+Home" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionMoveNextWord" shortcut="Meta+Shift+Right" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionMovePrevWord" shortcut="Meta+Shift+Left" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.MoveNextWord" shortcut="Meta+Right" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.MovePrevWord" shortcut="Meta+Left" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.LineEnd" shortcut="End" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.LineStart" shortcut="Home" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.PageUp" shortcut="Page_Up" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.PageDown" shortcut="Page_Down" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionMoveUp" shortcut="Shift+Up" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionMoveDown" shortcut="Shift+Down" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionMoveLeft" shortcut="Shift+Left" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionMoveRight" shortcut="Shift+Right" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionPageDownAction" shortcut="Shift+Page_Down" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.SelectionPageUpAction" shortcut="Shift+Page_Up" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.DeleteNextWord" shortcut="Meta+Delete" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.DeletePrevWord" shortcut="Meta+BackSpace" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.InsertNewLineAtEnd" shortcut="Shift+Return" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.TextEditorCommands.InsertNewLinePreserveCaretPosition" shortcut="Meta+Return" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.Save" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.WindowCommands.SwitchPreviousDocument" shortcut="Meta+Alt+E" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.WindowCommands.NextWindow" shortcut="Alt+Right" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.WindowCommands.PrevWindow" shortcut="Alt+Left" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.SearchCommands.FindNext" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.SearchCommands.FindPrevious" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.CodeFormatting.CodeFormattingCommands.FormatBuffer" shortcut="Meta+Alt+Shift+L" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Debugger.DebugCommands.ToggleBreakpoint" shortcut="Meta+F8" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.VersionMeta.Git.Commands.Stash" shortcut="Control+Shift+K" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.VersionMeta.Commands.UpdateSolution" shortcut="Control+T" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.VersionMeta.Commands.SolutionStatus" shortcut="Control+K" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorCommands.ToggleCodeFocus" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.VersionMeta.Git.Commands.ManageStashes" shortcut="Control+Shift+T" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.SearchCommands.Replace" shortcut="Meta+R" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.EditCommands.Rename" shortcut="Shift+F6" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Refactoring.RefactoryCommands.DeclareLocal" shortcut="Meta+Alt+V" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.NUnit.Commands.TestCommands.ShowTestCode" shortcut="F4" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.ViewCommands.ShowNext" shortcut="Meta+Alt+Down" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.ViewCommands.ShowPrevious" shortcut="Meta+Alt+Up" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Debugger.DebugCommands.EnableDisableBreakpoint" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.ProjectCommands.Stop" shortcut="Shift+F2" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Debugger.DebugCommands.SelectExceptions" shortcut="Meta+Alt+Shift+F8" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.CSharp.Highlighting.MoveToUsagesCommand.PrevUsage" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.CSharp.Highlighting.MoveToUsagesCommand.NextUsage" shortcut="" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.NavigationCommands.NavigateBack" shortcut="Alt+Meta+Left" />
    <binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.ViewCommands.PreviousNotebook" shortcut="Control+Shift+Z" />
  </scheme>
</schemes>
```